# Group a sorted strings of array into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object

input = ['abc', 'def','ghi', 'bac', 'fed', 'hgi', 'cab', 'edf', 'igh']

output = [{'abc', 'bac', 'cab'},{ 'def', 'edf', 'fed'}, {'ghi',  'hgi',  'igh'}]

Need to sort the array and group them by array of objects

Comment: `{'abc', 'bac', 'acb'}` is not a correct object - it needs keys and values

Comment: Is it a requirement that the objects have exactly 3 properties? Shouldn't each object rather have only 1 property with the text, and then sort them?

Comment: Yes that's the requirement we need to push strings of same characters in sorted order into a group of objects in a new array

Comment: first of all, output is not a valid array, you need to make a proper array for output

Comment: Items grouped into arrays (instead of the invalid objects you're demanding): https://jsfiddle.net/948bgt0k/1/ split/sort/join gets all the letters of an item into alphabetical order, which are then used as _object_ key for easier grouping. Object.values() then gets an array again out of those object properties.

Comment: Thanks CBroe for giving me an approach.. Here is the working fiddle for the output I have asked for [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/793pz2cu/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to sort objects by their keys;

```
const obj = {a: 'abc', c: 'ghi', b: 'def'};

const sortedObj = Object.keys(obj)
  .sort()
  .reduce((accumulator, key) => {
    accumulator[key] = obj[key];

    return accumulator;
  }, {});

console.log(sortedObj);
// Object { a: "abc", b: "def", c: "ghi" }
```

Technically, objects need explicit keys, that's what seperates them from arrays which have implicit keys. An array is a type of object. ONLY empty objects have no keys. and That's important because the array methods which are available for sorting elements are not applicable on objects.

Can you tell more about the context and how you plan to use this object? Any more information can help us know more to help you!